# Form submission error with request.user using a Class Based View and a custom ModelForm

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a record through a form and it will not submit or pass the information to the database. I am sure that the user is showing up in the HTML but it is not being sent with the request.

I am able to successfully create a record using the interactive shell with no problem and the test that I wrote passes. Following the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) and the link to add request.user (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)

Object/Model

```
class Event(models.Model, Activity):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    completion_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id, self.description or ''
```

views.py

```
class EventCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = 'app/event_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('event_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner_id = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'start_date', 'end_date',
                  'completion_date', 'description']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.owner_id = kwargs.pop('user')
            return super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the minimal working view and now the ModelForm is not needed.

```
#views.py

class EventCreate(CreateView):
    model = EventForm
    fields = ('name','start_date','end_date','completion_date','description')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('event_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner_id = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

2. Sent the request to a barebones HTML document

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Simple HTML</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Test Form">


</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Result: the form submits. 
Problem: a line of javascript was not playing nice. It has since been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi apowell656 if you are using class-based in view you need specific the model class, your example like this:

```
class EventCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
form_class = EventForm
model = Event
template_name = 'app/event_form.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('event_list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.owner_id = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that did not work, unfortunately. I thought this (https://colinkingswood.github.io/Model-Form-Customisation/) would get me closer to the desired result also, but sadly it did not.

Comment: Can you specify what is your desired result?

Comment: Sure, that the form is valid and the data entered in the database. I am currently trying to figure out why my view based test is considered invalid -- which explains why the form redirects to the same form.